# How to calculate difference from each month?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am trying to have the difference of cost over month, they are going to be columns and the cost codes are going to be rows. The image is an example of what I need using Power BI but I need it in the Power BI Report Builder.
[image: Photo of Power BI Example]

I tried setting it up in the report builder and looks like this:
[image: Photo from Report Builder]

This attempt was not giving me any difference from the previous month which is the column to the left.

If someone know anything around it please help, the database is in SQL.

Comment: share code as text instead of images please. The image of the expression cannot be the full expression as it's missing a closing ")"

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom code to get the previous value and calculate the difference

Add the following code to your report

```
Public Shared previous As Integer
Public Shared current As Integer
Public Shared count As Integer

  Public Shared Function SetPrevious( val as Integer) as Integer
     previous = current
     current = val
     count = count + 1
     return current
  End Function

  Public Shared Function GetDiff()
    If count = 1
     return Nothing 
    Else return current-previous
    End if
  End Function

  Public Shared Function ResetPrevious(groupname As String) As String
    previous = 0
    current = 0
    count = 0
    Return groupname
  End Function
```

Use ResetPrevious on your group cell
`=Code.ResetPrevious(Fields!phase.Value)`

Use SetPrevious on your current value cell
`=Code.SetPrevious(Sum(Fields!cost.Value))`

Use GetDiff on your difference value cell
`= Code.GetDiff()`

[image]

[image]